# Преобразование массива

Tags: массивы, php

Всем привет, стоит не обычная (на мой взгляд) задача преобразовать массив, без использования foreach или других циклов.

исходный массив
    array(1, 2, 3)
и переменная $a = 25
на выходе нужно получить массив

```
array(
    0 => array('customer' => 1, 'plan' => 25),
    1 => array('customer' => 2, 'plan' => 25),
    2 => array('customer' => 3, 'plan' => 25)
)
```

смотрел на array_fill и на array_replace но чтото так и не надумал как решить в 1 или 2 строчки

Comment: А решение без циклов -- это самоцель? Понятно же, что что бы вы не написали, внутри оно всё равно пробежит весь массив.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$a = 25;
$b = array(1, 2, 3);

array_walk($b, function(&$v) use ($a) { $v = array('customer' => $v, 'plan' => $a); });

print_r($b);
```

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [customer] => 1 [plan] => 25 ) [1] => Array ( [customer] => 2 [plan] => 25 ) [2] => Array ( [customer] => 3 [plan] => 25 ) )

PHP 5.3+
но зачем %)

Comment: Возможно вы правы, но я ожидал решения что то похожее на вызов
array_values совместно с array_replace.
Пожалуй вы правы - это ничем не лучше цикла :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function trololo($a,$b) {
   $z = function($a,$b){return array('costumer'=>$a, 'plan'=>$b);};
   return array($z($a[0],$b),$z($a[1],$b),$z($a[2],$b));
}

var_dump(trololo(array(0,1,3), 25));
```

Решение в лоб. Без циклов и максимально коротко. И в 2 строчки. Примеры же с `array_walk` и `array_map` используют перебор элементов массива, т.к. в процессе участвует цикл. Что-то я не понимаю намерений ТС :\

Answer (score 0):

я думаю, это максимально похоже на то, что Вам нужно:

```
<?php

 function fll($x) {
    $a = 25;
    return array("customer"=>$x, "plan"=>$a);
 }
 $m = array(1, 2, 3);

 var_dump($m);

 $c = array_map("fll", $m);
 var_dump($c);
?>
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но по сути это ничем не отличается от цикла.
Интересует именно красивое решение стандартными средствами.
Не хочу показаться занудой, но такова задача :)

Comment: как по мне, так красиво. Определили себе функции нужные, а потом используете. По факту - одна строка.

Код с анонимными функциями хорош, более того, его можно и здесь использовать, но не знаю, какой используется по факту.